# XML Serializable IQueryable<T>/Expression Tree

Tags: .net, xml, linq, serialization, xml-serialization

Is there any classes built in to .NET that will convert an expression tree or an `IQueryable<T>` to XML?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no.  [`IQuerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) is an interface, and as such, there can be many implementations behind it, each of them serializing differently.

That said, you could try and serialize the [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) that the [`IQueryable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) (the base of `IQueryable<T>`) exposes through the [`Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx).

The problem there is that the `Expression` class and it's subclasses are not serializable, so you would have to create a structure that is a mirror of the `Expression` class (and *all* of its subclasses, and there are many) and then serialize that.  Fortunately, there is the [Expression Tree Serialization project on MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization) which might help you.

Even then, you still won't have things like provider information, etc.  This may or may not impact what you are trying to do.

However, if all you need is to set the expression tree on an existing `IQueryable<T>` implementation, this should suffice.